# Ambiguous Reference after moving data class

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF web service, in the interface I had a data class...

```
public class ValidationError
{
    public string PLR;
    public string FieldName;
    public string ErrorText;
}
```

The web service returns `List<ValidationError>` I now need this same data class elsewhere in the app so I have moved it into a common project and added a reference in the interface.

In the web service it knows where everything and it doesn't complain when I build.  However since moving this class the Win Forms app that uses it is reporting....

`'ValidationError' is an ambiguous reference between 'MyApp.Common.DataClasses.ValidationError' and 'MyApp.Forms.UI.XMLValidationReference.ValidationError'`

I have deleted the class from the interface, updated the service reference, deleted the reference and re-referenced. Nothing has worked.  Am I missing something glaringly obvious here?

**UPDATE**

Since deleting all the file in all debug folder of all project I only have one of these errors left.

`List<ValidationError> tc2errors = new List<ValidationError>();` //Problem on first second is not ambiguous.

Four lines down

`ValidationError sve = new ValidationError();` Not ambiguous

How can it know where the data class is for all references but one?

Comment: Have you also shared the contract for the service between in the common location?

Comment: @JonEgerton im sure its nothing to do with sharing contracts.  I have just deleted all the files in debug folders for all project.  The 19 errors I was getting has now reduced to one.  Same error as the other 18 and in the same code, same project (the forms project). See the update for more info

Comment: I would say you'll continue to have problems, as there are two different versions of the class around (see the two different namespaces). You might get away with it if you never need to mix them - assign one to the other etc.

Comment: @JonEgerton I don't understand why I have two.  Its only in DataClasses. I moved it from the Web Service.

Comment: One is declared in the proxy class generated by the reference to the  WCF service. The other is declared by you in your common namespace. They're different, but similar looking classes. This is what I mean by making the whole contract interface common - then you only end up with one version of all the class definitions involved. (basically you don't use the proxy reference, just the known interface that you've already defined.)

Comment: Please mark my answer correct if it resolved your problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a using directive for the path you want to use, i.e.:

using ValidationError = MyApp.Common.DataClasses.ValidationError

or

using ValidationError = MyApp.Forms.UI.XMLValidationReference.ValidationError

(depending on which is now correct)